# PhoneGap geolocator using WiFi instead of GPS

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, geolocation

I am trying to implement geolocation on a PhoneGap App running on Android. For some reason the locator only returns accurate distances when connected WiFi (i.e. it prefers coarse over fine). My GPS is of course enabled. Note that at one point the app tried using GPS (I saw the locator blinker come up) but it kept timing out; upon restarting the device, it went back to only using WiFi. Attached is my code:

```
function testGeo(){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            $('#latitude').html('');
            $('#longitude').html('');
            $('#accuracy').html('');
            $('#latitude').html(position.coords.latitude);
            $('#longitude').html(position.coords.longitude);
            $('#accuracy').html(position.coords.accuracy);
            $('#loading-frame-geo').hide();
        }, GeoError, {enableHighAccuracy:true,maximumAge:3000,timeout:10000});  
}
```

I am using PhoneGap version 2.5.0 (for backwards compatibility with other features)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have have geolocation enabled in your config.xml: `<plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>`

And in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

Also try upping your timeout to 60000 - it can take a while for older devices to acquire a GPS fix.

Consider using `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` instead of `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`. This will add a watcher which calls the success function each time the device acquires a new position; the error callback will be called if a position fix hasn't yet been acquired.

One more thing (I found from experience) is that Android will silently fall back to Wifi or cell triangulation if it loses its GPS fix and there's nothing in the Position object passed to the success function to tell you what hardware the device is using to obtain its location. However, you can infer it from the accuracy and discard any positions that are too inaccurate, something like:

```
MIN_ACCURACY = 20; //metres

function success(position){
  if(position.coords.accuracy > MIN_ACCURACY){
    console.log("Position rejected because accuracy is less than required "+MIN_ACCURACY+" metres");
    return;
  }
  // else, do some stuff with the position
}
```

You might also want to consider using [this plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Diagnostic) to check if GPS is enabled on the device with `isGpsEnabled()` and if not, direct the user to the settings page with `switchToLocationSettings()`

Hope it helps...

Comment: I am actually using PhoneGap build so I simply added the feature name to config.xml